# Cassandra SSTables generation memory consumption / available compression?

Tags: cassandra, bulk-load

I am generating Cassandra SSTables using the bulk loading sample provided at DataStax website. http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading

My question is how much disk space is ideally consumed by the SSTable files ? In my case my data CSV file is 40 GB and the total disk space consumed by SStables for this specific file is around **250GB**. Is there something that I am missing while creating these tables ? Are there any compression options available for generating sstables ?

The second step where I am loading the sstables using sstableloader works perfectly fine and data is available for querying in CQL.

Also, I would like to know if there are anyother techniques available to import large data into cassandra other than the bulkload method that I have mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether compression is enabled or not. How to check that?

If the sstable is compressed it will have a **CompressionInfo.db** 
component (i.e. one of the file composing the sstable with end with 
--CompressionInfo.db). If there is no such file then it's not 
compressed.

For further compression related information, [check this](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/operations/tuning#configure-compression).

Moving to last question there is other alternative to bulkload method, use **COPY** command. See [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/cql/COPY)

Comment: Thanks Abhi. I understand the compression parameter that can be specified during creation of column family; but would this affect the way I am generating SStables using Cassandra IO API ? the only arguments required for generating sstables are the keyspace and column family name. Also, I have tried COPY command previously, but it requires the CSV to have a quoted structure something like "aa","bb" ... Can you share what techniques you are using to load data in Cassandra ?

Comment: Yes  it will definitely effect. Try that and No, no other mechanism to load except these two.

Comment: @amey i don't use bulk loading jobs. I prefer doing it manually, using threads, as i have to maintain lots of counter columns.

Comment: so do you use Hector/Astyanax to do bulk inserts ? How is the performance with that, in the sense how long does it take for like 10GB data ?

Comment: depends on system spec, in my case i can write up to 2000 records/core/second, as my records are quite complex. Now you can imagine what will be the exact time to load 10 GB data

Comment: Thanks for the insights Abhi. Are you using any Cassandra client like Hector to write records ?

Comment: i prefer astyanax. Recently thinking of migrating on datastax java driver after seeing its simple api